# Trying to make a Ticket Bot but gets TypeError: channel.updateOverwrite is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ticket-system

I want to make a Ticket System and in the ticket when you react with ✅ makes the channel view only from admins. (Closes the ticket.)

Code:

```js
if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
    if(!reaction.message.channel.name.includes('ticket-')) return
    reaction.users.remove(user)

    reaction.message.reactions.cache.get('✅').remove()
    reaction.message.reactions.cache.get('❌').remove()

    let channel = reaction.message

    channel.updateOverwrite("user.id", { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
}
```

Error:
`TypeError: channel.updateOverwrite is not a function`

Comment: From your code it seems like `channel` is only the `message` object, not the actual `channel` object. I think you just need to switch `let channel = reaction.message` to `let channel = reaction.message.channel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `channel` is not an instance of [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) but of [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), which is probably a mistake. To get the corresponding `GuildChannel` object, use the following: (as PerplexingParadox said in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583280/trying-to-make-a-ticket-bot-but-gets-typeerror-channel-updateoverwrite-is-not-a#comment121206145_68583280).)

```js
let channel = reaction.message.channel;
```

The next thing is that [`Collection.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) method accepts a key as its parameter, which is in this case the reaction id (or [Twitter Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)). To find a reaction by its name, you could do this:

```js
for (const emojiName of ["✅", "❌"]) {
    reaction.message.reactions.cache.find((reaction) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === emojiName;
    })?.remove();
}
```

And remove them if they are found using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

At last [`GuildChannel.updateOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite) accepts [`RoleResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable) or [`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) as its first argument. Passing in a user's id is correct, because it falls under `UserResolvable`. You probably accidentally added the quotation marks around the `user.id`. It is a variable, if you want it to be treated like one remove the quotation marks, otherwise it will be treated as nothing more but a string with a text inside. And won't work because text "user.id" is not a valid Twitter Snowflake.

```js
channel.updateOverwrite(user.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
```

Comment: Another way to get it is by doing this: `let { channel } = reaction.message`

Comment: @MrMythical Yep, depends on your syntactical preference what you use.